# TransactionScope and SQL Server Compact

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

SQL Server Compact doesn't support distributed transactions. So if there are more than one connection inside TransactionScope - the exception is thrown. Is there any way to setup ADO.NET provider to use one connection for the same connection string?

I understand I can use usual transactions through connection.BeginTransaction but TransactionScope is preferable for me.

**UPDATE**.
Sorry, I didn't mention I work with Entity Framework, so I have no control on SQL Command. I may just pass connection string. And by some reason several connections objects created for one connection string inside TransactionScope.

Comment: Can you provide some code? You can manually set the connection for your commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer (code sample from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c3fd7555-7fff-44b8-8e1e-030073c20597/)):

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    using (var txscope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        context.Connection.Open();
        // do query 1
        // do query 2
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Another solution, as you said, is to create a connection object and use it in constructors for the Object Context.

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx) about when Entities opens new connection.

Comment: But the @Idsa used that in his question. And it worked, as you can see from his own answer!

Comment: Don't know. Upvoted. Your solution will work for one ObjectContext. But I need one connection through several ObjectContext as I posted below. But I will mark your answer.

Comment: @leppie, SQLCE supports TransactionScope. It doesn't support distributed transactions

Comment: @Idsa Added your silution also.

Comment: My experience is that SQLCE does NOT support TransactionScope. Really easy to test yourself and prove me wrong. Just insert 1 row in one table and insert another row in another table and throw an error without committing the scope.

Comment: As stated above, SQLCE does not not support distributed transactions, not the `TransactionScope`

Comment: I stand corrected. There is a limitation with SQLCE that the connection should be opened within the transactionscope. I had the connection already opened that is why my test was not working. Here the technet article for further reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896149(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

My error was that I passed connection string to `ObjectContext`. If I pass connection object, only one connection is used.