# The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, transactionscope

I am using TransactionScope to test database actions. This is the test class:

```cs
// Test class

private TransactionScope _transactionScope = null;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
}

[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup()
{
    if (_transactionScope != null)
    {
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
        _transactionScope = null;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("Db.sdf")]
public void AddToPresentationsTest()
{           
    var item = TestItem();
    var db = new DbEntities();
    var target = new DatabaseController {Entities = db};
    target.AddToItems(item);
    var result = db.Items.Any(p => p.Text.Equals(item.Text));
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

A TransactionScope is created before each test and is disposed after the test is complete. When AddToItems method is called I get the following error:

`System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope.`

DatabaseController has the following code:

```
// DatabaseController class

private DbEntities _entities;

public DbEntities Entities
{
    get { return _entities ?? (_entities = new DbEntities());}
    set { _entities = value; }
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && _entities != null)
    {
        _entities.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

public void AddToItems(Item item)
{
    Entities.Items.Add(item);
    Entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I use Sql Server Compact 4.0. Could you please point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153573/error-on-using-transactionscope-in-ef4-sql-compact-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, TransactionScope needs to escalate to a distributed or nested transaction, [neither of which is supported by CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172400%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

This may be happening e.g. because more than one connection is being opened concurrently -
[TransactionScope and SQL Server Compact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690475/transactionscope-and-sql-server-compact)

CE does however support [lightweight transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896149%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), so in theory as long as all your connections use the same connection string, and that you close each connection before opening another, `TransactionScope` shouldn't escalate to distributed.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that SQL CE has such limitations.

Comment: @Ashton Hearts - I'm afraid I don't use CE much - there are some workarounds here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690475/transactionscope-and-sql-server-compact

Comment: Well, all the connections do actually use the same connection string. I also noticed that I get the error when calling a methods inside `DatabaseController`. Otherwise transaction scope works fine.